# Shorter alternative to Language Proficiency?

Tags: word-choice

I'm using "language proficiency" as a field name in a form where users are to key in the languages that they are proficient in (does not matter if written or oral).

However, the phrase is rather long.  Is there a shorter dummy down alternative?

Comment: I don't consider it long at all. Nor do I see why you should have to dummy it down. If the context were already understood, it could just be "languages," but it sounds as if that's not the case.

Comment: Are users likely to answer "Language Proficiency" with a rating like "high"? A prompt like "Languages Spoken" seems clearer to me.

Comment: "Languages Spoken", to me, is very different from "Language Proficiency". You could break down proficiency at least into "written" and "spoken".

Comment: What if you have a field for Language Proficiency and someone enters “Yes.”

Comment: Language skills - skills in place of proficiency makes it a little smaller ;)

Comment: @RamPillai that kinda slipped my mind. thanks.

Comment: @Xanne As in "Sex: frequent"?